# Centos, ubuntu, and windows

Tags: dual-boot, grubrescue

I recently partitioned my hardrive to install ubuntu alongside windows. I then went to install centos over ubuntu. After this second installiation, even after specifying where centos should be installed i could not boot off windows. I then went back to install ubuntu off centos to try to recover the grub menu. Now even after installing ubuntu, i only have the option to boot centos which obviously doesnt work because it no longer exists. So now i cant boot anything. I know the windows partition still exists. I can only access the centos grub command line. I tried putting boot rescue on my usb using unetbootin but it failed for some reason.

Anyideas? Thank you

Comment: Deleted the other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, looks like you may have to re-install GRUB. This should auto-detect any bootable partitions you have and allow you to boot from them.

Here's how: http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd

Comment: Thank you. I ended up getting boot-repair disk to work, should that help too?